# Hibernate second level cache, one to many

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache

I tried first time to use second level cache according different tutorials and it doesn't work. I have class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_NAME")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class Foo {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "foo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Sentence> collection_name;
```

and configuration in my hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
 <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
 <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
 <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
```

I turned on

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

I thought that second query won't hit database, but it does.

my Query :

```
  List<Foo> result = session.createQuery("select p from Foo p order by size(p.collection_name) desc ").list();
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cache your HQL quert result, you have to instrument your query:

```
List<Foo> result = session
                      .createQuery("select p from Foo p order ... ")
                      .setCacheable(true)
                      .list();
```

Additionaly you can tell Hibernate, which cache configuration (cache region) it should use:

```
List<Foo> result = session
                      .createQuery("select p from Foo p order ... ")
                      .setCacheable(true)
                      .setCacheRegion("foo_region")
                      .list();
```

Of course, global setting `hibernate.cache.use_query_cache` must be set to `true`.

`@Cache` annotation on entity class is used to cache single entity when it is fetched **by ID**:

```
Foo foo = session.get(Foo.class, fooId);
```

Answer (score 0):

In both the foo.java and Sentence.java specify

```
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
```

Also just after the `@OneToMany` annotation specify

```
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
```

if you are using Query object:

```
Query q 
enable the cacheable to true
```